# How can I import umd with <script type="module"> into browser including node_modules

Tags: typescript, browser, node-modules, es6-modules, html-imports

Can I somehow transpile typescript code and import it into the browser without Webpack? I am using node_modules in the code so this is making it a bit complicated.

I have tried to import it as a module:

```
<script type="module">
   import * as foo from '../../dist/index.js';
   console.log(foo);
</script>
```

But it imported only this strange thing:

```
Module {Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"}
```

The best option for me would be to transpile it as **umd** so it can be universally imported into the browser / imported as a node_module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it depends on the content of imported file.

For example, if *index.js* is like below:

```
export const x = "Hello World"
export function y() { console.log( "y()" ) }
```

Then with your code you should use `foo.x` to access the `x` value, or `foo.y()` to invoke the `y()` function.

You could also get only one exported object by using another syntax:

```
<script type="module">
   import {x} from '../../dist/index.js';
   console.log(x);
</script>
```